# I'm having a problem with a node js project, my server wont respond and will throw me an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

My js file wont respond and it will trow me this error in the console wich i don't understand:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Backend server is running
Connected to MONGODB
(node:5282) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation 
`users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/francesco/Desktop/Projects/Social Network/NODE-REST- 
API/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:149:23)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5282) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or 
by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node 
process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled- 
rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5282) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. 
In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the code of the module (btw dont mind but th "ok" its for testing.

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const User = require("../models/User")

//REGISTER
router.get("/register", async (req,res)=>{
const user = await new User({
    username:"john",
    email:"john@gmail.com",
    password:"123456"
})

await user.save();
res.send("ok");
});

module.exports = router
```

the syntax is right, needed to format it for containing on the "code" on the question.
Thanks in advance, Francesco

Comment: You are getting the error `MongooseError: Operation 'users.insertOne()' buffering timed out after 10000ms`. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: check your `mongoose.connect()` function for errors - mongoose can't connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the model without even establishing a connection with the database. You need to use async/await with connect() or createConnection().